# How to override a theme function?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using [LoginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) as my login page, and on the login form, it has: "You are not logged in." I want to be able to edit this text, and the admin interface doesn't give an option to do so.

Searching around, I see that this is set in the LoginToboggan module in a theme function:

```
function theme_lt_unified_login_page($variables) {
...
$output .= '<div id="login-message">' . t('You are not logged in.') . '</div>';
...
}
```

So I can't edit the module directly, nor would I wish to "patch" it. I see that `theme_lt_unified_login_page` is called by:

```
function logintoboggan_unified_login_form($active_form = 'login') {
...
$output = theme('lt_unified_login_page', $variables);
...
}
```

I don't really understand what hook I would use to intercept and override / edit just this text? It doesn't appear in the `$form` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest way might be/would be to copy...

```
/**
 * Theme function for unified login page.
 *
 * @ingroup themable
 */
function theme_lt_unified_login_page($variables) {

  $login_form = $variables['login_form'];
  $register_form = $variables['register_form'];
  $active_form = $variables['active_form'];
  $output = '';

  $output .= '<div class="toboggan-unified ' . $active_form . '">';

  // Create the initial message and links that people can click on.
  $output .= '<div id="login-message">' . t('You are not logged in.') . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div id="login-links">';
  $output .= l(t('I have an account'), 'user/login', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('login-link'), 'id' => 'login-link')));
  $output .= ' ';
  $output .= l(t('I want to create an account'), 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('login-link'), 'id' => 'register-link')));

  $output .= '</div>';

  // Add the login and registration forms in.
  $output .= '<div id="login-form">' . $login_form . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div id="register-form">' . $register_form . '</div>';

  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

to your theme's template.php file and rename it...

```
/**
 * Theme function for unified login page.
 *
 * @ingroup themable
 */
function YOURTHEME_lt_unified_login_page($variables) {

  $login_form = $variables['login_form'];
  $register_form = $variables['register_form'];
  $active_form = $variables['active_form'];
  $output = '';

  $output .= '<div class="toboggan-unified ' . $active_form . '">';

  // Create the initial message and links that people can click on.
  $output .= '<div id="login-message">' . t('PLACE YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE.') . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div id="login-links">';
  $output .= l(t('I have an account'), 'user/login', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('login-link'), 'id' => 'login-link')));
  $output .= ' ';
  $output .= l(t('I want to create an account'), 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('login-link'), 'id' => 'register-link')));

  $output .= '</div>';

  // Add the login and registration forms in.
  $output .= '<div id="login-form">' . $login_form . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div id="register-form">' . $register_form . '</div>';

  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

...along with whatever you wanted that `login-message` to be.  Clear caches/theme registry and you should be on your way.

ADDITION:

This ***drupal fu*** works because, instead of calling `theme_lt_unified_login_page()` directly, it does it like this:

```
$output = theme('lt_unified_login_page', $variables);
```

and it is the `theme()` function that does the magic in that when you build the theme registry, it will discover that there is a *YOURTHEME*_lt_unified_login_page() function out there, and will call that as an override to the *theme*_lt_unified_login_page() one that logintoboggan provides.

(Note that the first argument doesn't start with `theme_` or `YOURTHEME_`, one of these are prepended by the theme system as described above.)

Comment: Interesting; although I'm a little confused how this works - I assumed that `theme_lt_unified_login_page` was a function unique to the logintoboggan module that would be called at some point in a hook - how does Drupal know that the replacement function in `template.php` should take the place of the one in `logintoboggan.module`?

Comment: see additions to answer for some more information.  http://drupal.org/documentation/theme is a good start as well for lots more info on drupal theming.