# How to customize pager

Tags: 7, theming, paging

I have a code, that outputs a standard pager:

```
print theme('pager');
```

it outputs this:

```
<h2 class="element-invisible">Pages</h2>
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="pager"><li class="pager-current first">1</li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 2" href="/drupal/node?page=1">2</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 3" href="/drupal/node?page=2">3</a></li>
<li class="pager-next"><a title="Go to next page" href="/drupal/node?page=1">next ›</a></li>
<li class="pager-last last"><a title="Go to last page" href="/drupal/node?page=5">last »</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I change the HTML to something like this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
</ul>
```

I looked into this thread: https://www.drupal.org/node/387786, created a function `bartik_preprocess_custom_pager` and a file `custom-pager.tpl.php` inside my Bartic theme templates, but I can't make it work.

```
print theme('custom_pager');
```

outputs nothing. Does anybody know, how can I customize the HTML output for a pager, creating one just for 1 page?

Comment: You also need to declare the new theme function in `hook_theme()`, or Drupal will not know there is a new theme function. Clear the cache after changing a theme.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I added the pager template into the function, and it's being called. But how can I pass the appropriate variables into the pager? They were passed automatically, when I called `theme('pager');`. Now I don't get them.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Hi. Is it possible to customize a pager inside a module? By creating a function mymodule_pager($variables)?

Comment: You can do it from a module too, but in that case you need to implement another hook too.

Comment: Theme functions gets `$variables` automatically; you just need to implement `hook_theme()` correctly. For changing a theme function from a module, the hook to implement is [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7).

Comment: There are a bunch of things wrong here: 1) you're using code specifically written for Drupal 6 ([see the "Drupal Version" tag on the page you got the code from](https://www.drupal.org/node/387786)), 2) you haven't named the function correctly (if you were using Drupal 6, you'd name the function exactly as it is in the example). Given how similar the markup you need is to the markup Drupal gives you, I'd be inclined to solve the problem with CSS.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out in my comment above, most of the details are wrong in your implementation above. Fortunately in Drupal 7, there are **six** theming functions for the pager:

- [theme_pager()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7)
- [theme_pager_first()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_first/7)
- [theme_pager_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_link/7)
- [theme_pager_last()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_last/7)
- [theme_pager_previous()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_previous/7)
- [theme_pager_next()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_next/7)

These should allow you to make most of the customizations that you need. [There's a good stackexchange answer about how to override Drupal theme functions() that you can refer to for the details](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75280/how-to-override-a-theme-function).

Finally, you mentioned that you want to override the pager just for one page. I still think this might be worth doing with CSS alone, but in case it's not, you may be able to just override parts of the `$variables` array in whichever preprocess function contains the pager (I don't know off the top of my head if it's `preprocess_page` or `preprocess_node` or if it's accessible from any of the preprocess functions at all).

Answer (score 2):

[This is my answer from a previous post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156493/add-a-class-to-the-first-li-pager-item-for-views-pager/156780#156780).

If you implement [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) you'll be expected to create the entire pager render array from scratch using several theme function - [theme_pager_first](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_first/7), [theme_pager_previous](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_previous/7), [theme_pager_next](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_next/7) and [theme_pager_last](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_last/7). That seems like entirely too much work for adding one class.

Since [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) calls [theme_item_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) at the very end to build the final render array, you can use [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to modify the pager render array before drupal renders it into HTML.

```
function THEME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // make sure we're dealing with a pager item list
  if (isset($vars['attributes']['class']) && in_array('pager', $vars['attributes']['class'])) {
    // make sure there are items
    if (count($vars['items'])) {
      $vars['items'][0]['class'][] = 'test';
    }
  }
}
```

Clear the cache after adding this hook.

**UPDATE**: find the first li.pager-item:

```
function THEME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // make sure we're dealing with a pager item list
  if (isset($vars['attributes']['class']) && in_array('pager', $vars['attributes']['class'])) {
    // loop the items and find the first .pager-item
    foreach ($vars['items'] as $index => $item) {
      if (in_array('pager-item', $item['class'])) {
        $vars['items'][$index]['class'][] = 'test';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE2**: find first and last li.pager-item:

```
function THEME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // make sure we're dealing with a pager item list
  if (isset($vars['attributes']['class']) && in_array('pager', $vars['attributes']['class'])) {

    // loop the items and find the first and last .pager-item
    $first = FALSE;
    $last = NULL;
    foreach ($vars['items'] as $index => $item) {
      if (in_array('pager-item', $item['class'])) {

        // first
        if (!$first) {
          $vars['items'][$index]['class'][] = 'test';
          $first = TRUE;
        }

        // last
        $last = $index;
      }
    }

    if (!empty($last)) {
      $vars['items'][$last]['class'][] = 'test2';
    }
  }
}
```