# Add a class to the first li.pager-item for a view pager?

Tags: views, theming

How can I add a class to the first li.pager-item and a different class to the last li.pager-item for for a Views pager?

I know that I need to make a theme override of theme_pager
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7

However I cant figure out what PHP to change.

Comment: Just add your style in Row class of the view. Maybe it can help

Comment: No the rows are part of the views results results. The pager is separate.

Comment: The pager creates a few different types of items. It usually creates numbers to click on. But, depending on where you are it can also create the first, prev, next, and last links. All of those are put into the same list. Do you want to add a class to the first item, no matter what type it is, or are you trying to get at the first number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) you'll be expected to create the entire pager render array from scratch using several theme function - [theme_pager_first](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_first/7), [theme_pager_previous](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_previous/7), [theme_pager_next](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_next/7) and [theme_pager_last](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_last/7). That seems like entirely too much work for adding one class.

Since [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) calls [theme_item_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) at the very end to build the final render array, you can use [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to modify the pager render array before drupal renders it into HTML.

```
function THEME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // make sure we're dealing with a pager item list
  if (isset($vars['attributes']['class']) && in_array('pager', $vars['attributes']['class'])) {
    // make sure there are items
    if (count($vars['items'])) {
      $vars['items'][0]['class'][] = 'test';
    }
  }
}
```

Clear the cache after adding this hook.

**UPDATE**: find the first li.pager-item:

```
function THEME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // make sure we're dealing with a pager item list
  if (isset($vars['attributes']['class']) && in_array('pager', $vars['attributes']['class'])) {
    // loop the items and find the first .pager-item
    foreach ($vars['items'] as $index => $item) {
      if (in_array('pager-item', $item['class'])) {
        $vars['items'][$index]['class'][] = 'test';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE2**: find first and last li.pager-item:

```
function THEME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // make sure we're dealing with a pager item list
  if (isset($vars['attributes']['class']) && in_array('pager', $vars['attributes']['class'])) {

    // loop the items and find the first and last .pager-item
    $first = FALSE;
    $last = NULL;
    foreach ($vars['items'] as $index => $item) {
      if (in_array('pager-item', $item['class'])) {

        // first
        if (!$first) {
          $vars['items'][$index]['class'][] = 'test';
          $first = TRUE;
        }

        // last
        $last = $index;
      }
    }

    if (!empty($last)) {
      $vars['items'][$last]['class'][] = 'test2';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If im not on the first page of the pagination then this class is added to li.pager-first, not the first li.pager-item.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the code to find the first li.pager-item

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. I also need a class on the last li.pager-item. Thanks

Comment: Answer updated based on new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Joudry's answer is correct. However when your on the first page of a view. The li has a class of pager-current not pager-item as it isnt a link. Therefore if you want to add a class to the the li that contains the text "1" then use this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // make sure we're dealing with a pager item list
  if (isset($vars['attributes']['class']) && in_array('pager', $vars['attributes']['class'])) {

    // loop the items and find the first and last .pager-item
    $first = FALSE;
    $last = NULL;
    foreach ($vars['items'] as $index => $item) {
      if ((in_array('pager-item', $item['class'])) or ( in_array('pager-current', $item['class']))) {

        // first
        if (!$first) {
          $vars['items'][$index]['class'][] = 'test';
          $first = TRUE;
        }

        // last
        $last = $index;
      }
    }

    if (!empty($last)) {
      $vars['items'][$last]['class'][] = 'test2';
    }
  }
}
```