# How to theme a preprocess function output with a default, without the need of a .tpl file?

Tags: theming

I created this simple function in order to print out the commerce order author UID and email.

**How may I add the output of the function inside the messages area, without creating a special .tpl?** I want that information to be in a special place regardless of the theme implementation.

This is the preprocess function (the only way I manage to get to know if I was [inside an order](https://www.drupal.org/node/1214104))

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    //si estamos dentro de la orden, lo sabemos sólo en función del link en el que estamos!
    $uri = request_uri();
    $find = '/admin/commerce/orders/';
    $pos = strpos($uri, $find);
    if ($pos !== false){
        //usando if (commerce_order_type_get_name($type = 'order')) no andaba
        //obtenemos el número de orden: obtenemos el link con request_uri()
        //y de ahí lo explotamos en un array. Sabemos que el número será siempre 
        //la última parte del link (4).
        //usamos commerce_order_load('id de la orden') para obtener el usuario que la completó
        $uri = request_uri();
        $partes = explode('/', $uri);
        $usuario = commerce_order_load($partes[4])->uid;
        $correo = commerce_order_load($partes[4])->mail;
        $estado = commerce_order_load($partes[4])->status;
        echo "<div class='messages status'><a href='/user/".$usuario."'>".$correo."</a> (".$estado.")</div>";

    }

}
```

As you can see, I've tried with this horrible:

```
echo "<div class='messages status'><a href='/user/".$usuario."'>".$correo."</a> (".$estado.")</div>";
```

Even when the classes are the same as the rest of the drupal messages, the output keeps appearing at the very top of the page.

How may I do it the right way? (Maybe it [necessarily involves template.tpl file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75280/how-to-override-a-theme-function))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that I could simply use [drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7)!

```
drupal_set_message(t("<a href='/user/".$usuario."'>".$correo."</a> (".$estado.")"), 'status');
```